# VB.net get every nth record from array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have dynamic array which receives thousands of records per minute, I am trying to achieve:

Using timer I need to take records from main array. Every 1 second process should access main array and take 20 records, then after second it will take next 20 records, etc...

What is the best and fastest way to achieve this?

I have main array which holds thousands of records which are constantly growing:

```
Public Shared myBigArray() As String = {}
```

New items are being added to array using:

```
Module Module2
<Extension()>
Public Sub Add(Of T)(ByRef arr As T(), item As T)
    Array.Resize(arr, arr.Length + 1)
    arr(arr.Length - 1) = item
End Sub
End Module

myBigArray.Add(message)
```

To copy records from main array to new array I use:

```
Array.Copy(myBigArray, smallArray, 20)
```

I need to loop copy procedure so it copies new records, 20 next records with each request.

Comment: Please show something about the code you have tried so far.

Comment: The answer to this question will be depend on the way you are using the array. When you take the top 20 items, should they be removed from the source array? If so, that sounds more like a *queue* than an array. If you're going to stick with an array, that's going to result in a lot of array resizing, which will result in very poor performance and lead to many garbage collections.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong type, especially if you keep on resizing the array. Use a [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) it's done for what you want, put items at the end, pull items at the beginning.

Comment: I didn't know about Queue. Thank you guys, I will study more about Queue.

Comment: If you need to operate in 1 second intervals, take a look at the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and set the `Interval` to `1000` milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, now I'm testing queue, how to get range, example: first 20 records (from 0 to 19), then with next call get next 20 records (from 19 to 39), etc...

Answer (score 0):

In class, where you have your timer defined, you need to define private integer variable, let's say `countOfReads` which will indicate how many times elements from array were read.

Then you can use this to fetch data from array - entries between `20*countOfReads` and `20*(countOfReads+1) - 1` for `countOfReads` starting from 0 (first read, so indexes will be between 0 and 19), etc.

Usage:

```
For i = countOfReads * 20 To (countOfReads + 1)*20 - 1)
    ' fetch your elements with myArray(i)
Next
' increment counter
countOfReads = countOfReads + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want it fast, you should not resize Arrays. Lists should be more suitable in that case. For both you should keep in mind the max size of Int32.MaxSize (about 2 bil).

**Example** (Still needs some error checking etc.):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim myBigList as New List(of string)

        'debug: fill with random nu
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            myBigList.Add("string_" & i)    
        Next

        Dim _startpos As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 1 to 5
            Console.WriteLine("_startpos:" & _startpos )
            For Each _s As String in myBigList.GetRange(_startpos,20)
                Console.WriteLine(_s)
            Next
            _startpos += 20
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: But how to get range, example: first 20 records (from 0 to 19), then with next call after a second next 20 records (from 19 to 39), etc...

Comment: myBigList.GetRange([STARTPOS],20), Startpos is 0-based